# Requesting help / assistance on NAT VyOS configuration

Tags: router, nat, vyos

i would like to request help / assistance on NAT VyOS configuration.
i'm new to it, so please bear with me :)

please see link for the sample diagram. https://i.ibb.co/kx1N6pD/NAT.png

from the diagram, what i would like to accomplish is to configure NAT
from my VyOS. this is to be able to host private servers (10.10.10.0/24) to public (internet).
but i want specific public ip address to specific private ip address NAT.

example: if a client visit sub1.domain.com (123.123.123.100) this public IP address
should only corresponds to 10.10.10.100 private server. this would be the same as for other subdomains
(color coded to match public to private ip address)

how do i start, and what would likely the configuration for this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SNAT configuration gives a decent explaination: [VyOS SNAT](https://wiki.vyos.net/wiki/NAT#SNAT_some_Networks).  I tested something similar in my lab and it worked as expected.

```
interfaces {
    ethernet eth0 {
        address 192.168.50.151/24
        address 192.168.50.161/24
    }
    ethernet eth1 {
        address 10.255.255.151/24
    }
}
nat {
    source {
        rule 100 {
            destination {
                address 192.168.50.51/32
            }
            outbound-interface eth0
            source {
                address 10.255.255.50/32
            }
            translation {
                address 192.168.50.161
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only real difference between the sample code above and the link is the addition of the **translation** directive, which states which IP address on eth0 to use.  In my lab my client is 10.255.255.50 and the destination is 192.168.50.51.  For your config you'll just have to tinker with the ordering of the rules as they are first-match.

Comment: thanks j123qwe, will try to use this